# Why error in phpmyadmin connecting to mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Running phpmyadmin on my local ubuntu 18
I got error

```
#1698 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

But in file /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
I changed connection parameters to escape default user as :

```
$dbuser='MYUSER';
$dbpass='MYPASSWORD';
$basepath='';
$dbname='phpmyadmin';
$dbserver='localhost';
$dbport='3306';
$dbtype='mysql';
```

Under MYUSER/MYPASSWORD I connect to my sql from my php apps.
In information_schema I run

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'lardev'@'localhost'
```

with output :

```
Query executed OK, 0 rows affected.
```

Why root user is refrerence in error message and how to fix the error ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables you have put in to `config.inc.php` aren't the correct variables for phpMyAdmin. You can refer to the [sample configuration files](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#config-examples), [documentation on all configuration directives](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html), or the file `config.sample.inc.php` that should be included with your download ([or can be viewed at Github](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/config.sample.inc.php)) for details on the correct syntax.

The official default is to use an authentication type called cookie, where you are prompted for the username and password when attempting to log in (you can see this [in action on the demo server](https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master/)). Your description sounds like you aren't prompted for a username, which means someone has changed to the 'config' authentication type, with a directive like `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';` The relevant difference (aside from security and how you go about logging in) is that with auth_type config, you also need to set the username and password in the configuration file. With the auth_type cookie or http, those values aren't used.

With that being said, here's a corrected version of `config.inc.php` using the configuration you've listed, using the phpMyAdmin variable names:

```
<?php

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'MYUSER';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'MYPASSWORD';
```

'localhost' is the default hostname, [which forces the connection to use sockets rather than TCP/IP networking](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php), so the port is ignored. To use a TCP/IP connection, set `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';`

The other variables, $basepath, $dbname, and $dbtype, have no direct equivalent to phpMyAdmin.

Also, note that I suggest using auth_type cookie rather than config in any situation where your web server would serve phpMyAdmin to connections not coming from localhost (as a security measure, otherwise anyone with the URL has direct access to your database).